# Adding .png image to the title property - ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

[image: ss]

How do I add an image to the title tab of the website? Thank you. Btw I'm using ASP.Net MVC4

Comment: Are you talking about the favicon, shown on the browser tabs? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the response! From my researching over the internet I found this solution

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/MyIcon.ico")">
```

Answer (score 0):

the icon which is displayed before the title text is called favicon, 
have a look on 
[this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/afenster/add-a-favicon-to-your-Asp-Net-page/)